# Retrieving data from multiple nodes in neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to retrieve related data from multiple related nodes with the following cypher:

```
Match (n {email:{paramEmail}})-[*..3]-(m) Return n,m",
       { paramEmail: email})
```

The problem is if there are no existing relationship as yet then I get zero rows returned...user not found though the user(n) exist but at this point have no relationships. I still need the properties from the user(n) node so I have to make a separate call. Is there a query that would return n even though there was no relationship with m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, match on the user with the email first, and then use an OPTIONAL MATCH for the rest:

```
MATCH (n {email:{paramEmail}})
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[*..3]-(m) Return n,m
```

Also, I'd advise you to use labels on your nodes. That way you could look up a :User by their email quickly (after creating an index on :User(email)). Right now the query has to scan all nodes of your graph to find those with the given email parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I do use labels and index on my searches.